# Some puzzles just appear while doing diy

Tags: topology

I had fitted a camera above the built-in wardrobe in our children's room. There was a socket behind the drawers. I could just remove the drawer to plug it in, but there was only enough room to slide the wire up the six inches or so behind the next drawer up that had a back on it so I couldn't feed it up one drawer at a time.  With no coat hanger to fish down the back, how did I get the wire up the back of the wardrobe? 
There were no gaps on the sides.

Comment: Maybe you should try diy.stackexchange.com? :-P

Comment: I think a photo of the wardrobe would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange! This seems an interesting puzzle but it seems unlikely that it will result in just one obviously correct answer based off what is currently given, which could result in it being taken down if that is the case. Take a look at the tour for this site to get a better idea of the restrictions on puzzles here and enjoy your time with the puzzling community! Tour link: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: CG it's a puzzle i have solved,  not one i need help with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whole project will just fall in to place.

> Just using the one drawer slot you already opened, let the power cord dangle down from the camera on top letting gravity help you out. Reach in through the slot, grab the cord, and plug it in.

Comment: The power cord is attached to the transformer so doesn't fit behind the wardrobe.

Answer (score 1):

Visualizing your process, my guess is that you

> Removed all of the drawers first, wired it up, then replaced all of the drawers.

Comment: Good answer but one of the drawers has a solid back so can't feed up through it.